# cyclopropane's reaction with lithium aluminium hydride

Tags: organic-chemistry

what is cyclopropane's reaction with lithium aluminium hydride? I think it must lead to ring-opening but I didn't find any article favoring this in my texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cyclopropanes do not react with LiAlH4. Substituents of cyclopropanes rings may be reduced with std LiAlH4 conditions with the cyclopropane ring being untouched

[example in this patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6943184B2/en)

Comment: but cyclopropane is an extremely strained structure and hydride could attach its LUMO leading to ring-opening and thus releasing strain. And if the reaction isn't happening what are constraints that oppose it?

Comment: LiAlH4 is not really a source of naked H-. The reaction generally runs through Al complexation to the substrate before H- transfer. There's nothing for Al to bind to with a cyclopropane.

Comment: shouldn't sn2 reaction of ammonia on methyl chloride increase if we use polar aprotic solvent because otherwise in polar protic solvent ammonia would be h-bonded and additional energy to overcome but I was rated wrong for this my test and the correct answer said that rate would increase if we use polar protic solvent.

Comment: That is a separate question

Comment: you are right .they said I can post only one question every 40 minutes but this way I won't be able to complete my assignment even in several days.so sir please and thank you.

Comment: Polar aprotic eg DMSO or SMF will still H-Bond with NH3 as it is both donor and receiver. SN2 is accelerated by polar solvents.